# What is the dialog background color of Theme.Holo.Dialog?

Tags: android

I have some questions related to the Dialog

1. how can i add an icon and title in xml style file. I know that I can use setTitle & setIcon in the code but i would prefer to make all style and GUI in xml as much as i can. just as some sort of organization
2. I liked the style of Theme.Holo.Dialog but how can I get the its background color? or if anyone its color code/name please provide me with it.

So if I want to use the background color of Theme.Holo.Dialog into another application Activity, should I change andriod:/colorbackground or background or windowbackground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the correct answer and try it myself:

1- Create an activity, apply the required Theme on it (Theme.Holo.Dialog)

2- get the exact resource id of the window background color:

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowBackground, tv, true);
String val = (String) tv.coerceToString();
```

Got the result as follows:
dialog_full_holo_dark.9.png
then I download it from the following [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-vlc-remote/source/browse/res/drawable-xhdpi-v11/dialog_full_holo_dark.9.png?r=9c3e53f10dd2b64e87b309fe3310679f2a5cf762)